# Should first name and middle name have a space on the U.S. passport?

Tags: usa, passports

I applied for the U.S. passport, and they put my first name and middle name together WITHOUT any delimiter. I was expecting to see FIRSTNAME SPACE MIDDLENAME. However, it shows as FIRSTNAMEMIDDLENAME no spaces. Is this OK? Or is this an error? Here is the image.  I replaced  actual name: I was hoping to see “JOHN DAVID”, but got “JOHNDAVID”

[image]

Comment: I assume the machine readable zone also has no space (i.e not: JOHN<DAVID). This will only cause you problems and should be replaced as faulty.

Answer (score 9):

Although spaces are frequently removed between the first name and any middle names in many travel documents, a passport isn't somewhere that this should be done.  Your first and middle name(s) should be separated with a space.

The first line of the "Machine Readable Area" (the two-line block of text at the bottom of the biographical page) should also show a break between these names - although there it should be a < character.  The first line should be :

`P<USASURNAME<<FIRST<MIDDLE<<<<<`

The good news is that there is a simple and free process to get this corrected. The process is described on the [US State Departments website](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/have-passport/change-correct.html) - just select the "Correct a Data or Printing Error" and follow the instructions provided.

Comment: Of course, that simple and free process involves surrendering your passport for upwards of three months.